# NestJS in Express mode - log all incoming requests

Tags: express, nestjs

`FastifyAdapter` logger is pretty helpful in logging all the incoming requests:

```
{"level":30,"time":1615660286373,"pid":4,"hostname":"6bc78f92-9bd6-4dfb-bd11-ae4c17a67f7c","reqId":19,"res":{"statusCode":304},"responseTime":6.005196988582611,"msg":"request completed"}
```

That's how I used it in Fastify mode/adapter:

```ts
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
   AppModule,
   new FastifyAdapter({logger: true})
)
```

Is there something similar in Express mode/adapter? Ideally without writing custom logging logic. It looks like a pretty common feature after all.

I checked `ExpressAdapter` source but it doesn't seem to have "log" being mentioned at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. If you need this feature you should install the logger that fastify uses: [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino), and [pino-http](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-http) to enable this yourself. Or just use [nestjs-pino](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino) (which will do this for you)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Micael's answer, there's an Express middleware called [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) that can do this, and if you're open to the idea of a different logger there's my own called [Ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) that has an interceptor for Nest that mimics this logic.